# Maven project builds fine from maven command line, but not with IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.1

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

1.From Maven command line, I type `mvn idea:module` and all dependencies builds fine,and successful import IntelliJ IDEA,all is fine.

2.After i type `mvn idea:clean`,clean all build.
In IntelliJ IDEA, in the right navigation bar, I click *Add Maven Projects*, choose `pom.xml`, then IntelliJ always shows *Resolving Maven Dependencies* in Background Tasks.

In my project, I use private Nexus repositories.

Very strange why IntelliJ doesn't tell me why to resolve maven dependencies on always!

I want to know why two kinds of ways to import projects have different results.

Comment: IntelliJ will rebuild and reimport whenever it detects changes in the maven project structure.  Don't use maven from the command line, let IntelliJ detect the various artifacts, and all should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have pom.xml you can open it from `File->Open Project`. Maven always works great in Intellij for me, never had to Add Maven Projects before.

Comment: I open pom.xml from `File->Open Project`，but the results and the above and `Resolving Maven Dependencies` always processes in Background Tasks.

Comment: Maybe there's some connectivity issue to the repositories when Intellij tries to connect there. Try checking proxy/firewall settings and if it still doesn't work open a defect at [their site](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/)

Comment: I see.Because of my project inner dependencies issue. My current project depends on another inner project,one of the dependencies in this two project has conflicts.It ruled out just fine in the current project.thanks all the same.